# Keras Mobilenet inference time increased after retraining. Is this normal?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I used `MobileNet` model to get the `Embeddings/Features` for 1000 images like:

```
model = MobileNet(weights ="imagenet", include_top = False, input_shape = (224,224,3), pooling = "avg")
output = model.predict(img)
```

it took 7 minutes for 1000  images. Then I trained the model using [Siamese Network with Binary Loss](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/12/07/comparing-images-for-similarity-using-siamese-networks-keras-and-tensorflow/) as:

```
model.trainable = True
 
inp1 = Input(shape = input_shape)
inp2 = Input(shape = input_shape)

emb1 = model(inp1)
emb2 = model(inp2)

distance = Lambda(euclidean_distance)([emb1, emb2]) # I have a euclidean_distance Function defined
outputs = Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(distance)
modelTrain = Model(inputs=[inp1, inp2], outputs=outputs)
modelTrain.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

After training, I save the model weights and loaded the model as:

```
base_model   = tf.keras.models.load_model(modelPath) # this model is Siamese version with 2 inputs and Lambda Layer

# Extracting the feature extractor part only i.e MobileNet Only 
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Input(shape = (224, 224, 3)),
                                    base_model.layers[2]]) # 3rd layer if the MobileNet So it is just like the model in the starting

output = model.predict(img)
```

**Problem is that now the model is taking 11 minutes instead of 7 for the same 1000 images**.

Why this might be happening?